# save toggle value

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a field (CONTACT_URL) that changes when a checkbox is clicked, how do I keep the value of the checkbox after reload

JS:

```js
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord,getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import makeGetCallout from '@salesforce/apex/StripeAPIHandler.makeGetCallout';
import updateContactRecord from '@salesforce/apex/StripeAPIHandler.updateContactUrl';
import deleteContactRecord from '@salesforce/apex/StripeAPIHandler.deleteContactUrl';
import CONTACT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import CONTACT_EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import CONTACT_PHONE from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
import CONTACT_URL from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Contact_Stripe_URL__c';

const fields = [CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_PHONE, CONTACT_URL];


export default class ContactStripeComponent extends LightningElement {

    //Get Data from record
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields
    })
    contact;

    get customerName() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CONTACT_NAME);
    }

    get customerEmail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CONTACT_EMAIL);
    }

    get customerPhone() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CONTACT_PHONE);
    }

    get customerUrl() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CONTACT_URL)
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<template>
    <article class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner slds-text-heading_small">Insert Record in Stripe</div>
        <footer class="slds-card__footer">
            <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Contact">
                <h2>If you see the link contact is integrated</h2>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Contact_Stripe_URL__c" options={contact.data}>
                </lightning-output-field>
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                    <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
                        <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Integrate record</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" onclick={getCheckoutLink} data-id="checkbox" onchange={checkUrl}  checked={checkboxVal}
                            name="checkbox-toggle-16" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-16" />
                        <span id="checkbox-toggle-16" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Integrate</span>
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disconnected from Stripe</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </lightning-record-view-form>
        </footer>
    </article>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either save the value against a record, and when your page reloads, fetch the current state of the checkbox for that record, or use [Web Storage API's](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for persistence.